# CMD+F7 in IntelliJ on Mac activates CMD+SHIFT+F7

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm experiencing a weird issue with IntelliJ on MAC...
Hitting CMD+F7 (find usages) activates CMD+SHIFT+F7 (highlight usages).
No other combination of CMD has the same effect.

Has anyone experienced this too, or anything similar?

Comment: There's a somehow similar issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215103

Comment: What does it show when you hit CMD+F7 in Preferences | Keymap | Find Actions by Shortcut?

Comment: @ArseniyNisnevich, it shows "Find Usages in File" - the expected result...  
As to the issue you've mentioned before, it's actually the opposite case :)

Comment: This means the shortcut is recognised correctly. So it doesn't show "Highlight Usages" among the sample of actions on CMD+F7, right? In this case, I don't have other ideas what might have caused this so far. Please file a new issue and provide IDE logs archive: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: Thanks @ArseniyNisnevich! Yeah - I figured it's a really weird edge case or something like that...